# Composer downloads project under php folder

Tags: php, composer-php

My composer.phar file is under `xampp/php` folder. When I download cakephp through composer (by using command : `php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app myProject`), it downloads the project folder (i.e. myProject folder) under : `xampp/php/myProject`. Although it should download the project under htdocs folder.

How to download a project through composer under htdocs folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just indicate complete path to your project: 

`php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app /path-to-htdocs/myProject`

(disclaimer: I just tried with a global composer instalation, not throught a .phar, but it should work too)

Comment: Thanks,it works. But is it possible to directly download the project into htdocs folder, I mean without always setting the full path?

Comment: maybe moving your composer.phar to htdocs, yo can just do: php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app myProject     --- And get it work. I'm not so used to using composer throught .phar

Comment: So should I directly copy and paste composer.phar file from xampp/php to xampp/htdocs. Will it work? Or should I need run a command for this?

Comment: @Mona I think ill work if you just copy composer.phar to htdocs folder. I must admit I'm not sure though. Btw, why not try to install composer globally?

Comment: Okay, sure I'll try to install composer globally. Thank you.